# How to read from app preferences?

Tags: iphone, settings

I read [Apple Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW7) on this subject but couldn't figure it out.

I created a Settings bundle using the [following tutorial](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-create-an-iphone-preferences-file), and I tried accessing my preferences (edited manually) like this:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[self setShouldPlaySounds:[defaults boolForKey:@"play_sounds_preference"]];
```

for "Key" I used the key value entered in the xml editor (double click on Root.plist).
I know you can build preferences with "Identifier" key and "DefaultValue" but I don't want the settings to be accesible in the setting app, I just want two dictuinaries with some strings for my custom settings.

1. What am I doing wrong? Why can't I get the value of the preferences?
2. Is it simpler to create my own config file? Implementing a serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting the value anywhere? And what behavior are you seeing with respect to the value of shouldPlaySounds?

What happens if you execute this first?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"play_sounds_preference"];
BOOL result = [defaults synchronize]; // force immediate saving of defaults.
NSLog(@"[defaults synchronize] returned %d", result);
```

Comment: I ran your code and then read the value and it worked!
And after, I removed your code and it still wirked!
Then I added another row to the settings (manually) and again - no good.
Can you please explain why I have to run this code? Is it only suppose to run once? I can't run it again because then the users preferences will disapear.

Comment: Would you explain what "no good" looks like? Does app crash? And are you trying to retrieve values that have not yet been written?

Comment: It doesn't crash, I work with integer values (not like the question) and I get zero values if I don't use your code before.
Why do I need to do it? can you refer me to a blogpost or anything? Thanks!

Comment: Would show how you are *setting* the values? Until they are explicitly set, they will, of course, default to zero.